# Type erasure and accessors

Tags: c++, templates, derived, type-erasure

I used type erasure pattern in C++, i.e I hide a template class with an abstract class

```
class Base{

  virtual ~Base(){}

 //pure virtual methods...
};

template<typename T>
class Derived : Base{

Derived<T>(){}
~Derived(){}

//public methods...

private :
vector<T> datas;

};
```

problem : if I want to retrieve or modify datas, I have to use the Base class

how do I défine the accessors getDatas() and SetDatas(vector datas) ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused.  Why can't you put `getDatas()` and `SetDatas()` under public methods in `Derived`?

Comment: I thought type erasure was a *problem* which people tried to *solve*, not a pattern people tried to create. Type erasure is what happens with java generics because they aren't as powerful as C++ templates.

Comment: @the-alchemist: Because this is a polymorphic class hierarchy and derived class objects are accessed through a base class reference/pointer.

Comment: @Philip: See http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html

Comment: @Philip I used type erasure because I had in an external class a vector<Derived<T> > and I couldn't provide T

Comment: @sbi do you think boost.any coulf solve my current problem ?

Comment: @user408535: I suppose what `boost::any` does under the hood basically is what [stijn has shown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585278/c-type-erasure-and-accessors/3585434#3585434) you. If I was you, I'd try hard to use something off the shelf rather than cooking up my own. I bet this stuff is hard to get right at first try.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define a SetData( vector ) since std::vector needs a type, and obiously you cannot define SetData( std::vector< T > ) in the Base if you have no definition for T.

So if you really need this and think this is the way to go, you'll have to look into type dispatching (or make a hack using void*). Boost uses type dispatching in some places, else google provides examples.

**edit** simple example of what it can look like; not really type dispatching but more straightforward

```
class Base
{
public:
  template< class T >
  bool SetData( const std::vector< T >& t )
  {
    return SetData( static_cast< const void* >( &t ), typeid( t ) );
  }

protected:
  virtual bool SetData( const void*, const std::type_info& ) = 0;
};

template< class T >
class Derived : public Base
{
protected:
  bool SetData( const void* p, const std::type_info& info )
  {
    if( info == typeid( std::vector< T > ) )
    {
      const std::vector< T >& v = *static_cast< const std::vector< T >* >( p );
      //ok same type, this should work
      //do something with data here
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      //not good, different types
      return false;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: typeof doesn't exist in C++ ?

Comment: Yep, that's what you would need to do. I suppose this basically is what `boost::any` does under the hood, though. Frankly, I'd rather use `boost::any` than invent my own.

Comment: @stijn ok nice

but after all these answers, I become doubtful about my choice

if I could resolve vector<My_class<T> > without interface, this would be great

Comment: @sbi boost.any could be a solution but does it allow to access datas from the template class ?

Comment: My understanding is that you can't have pure virtual template member functions.  I think `Base` has to be a template class here.

Comment: @bshields the interest of Base is that it isn't template.

Maybe if virtual methods become simple methods, I can access Derived methods directly

Comment: @bshields: Ah, good catch, I hadn't seen that. Too bad. Still, something like this ought to work.

Comment: @bshields: you're completly right, fixed example so that it actually works

Answer (score 1):

Type erasure is a form of (run-time) ***polymorphism*** where derived classes are generated from a template.

As with all forms of polymorphisms, ***derived classes need to have something in common*** which can, syntactically, be expressed in the base class.

***Edit:***

OK, [stijn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585278/c-type-erasure-and-accessors/3585434#3585434) gave me an idea. While I still think you should use something off the shelf (`boost::any`), just for kicks, here's a sketch:

```
class Base
{
public:
  template< class T >
  bool SetData(const std::vector<T>& data)
  {
    return SetData(&data,typeid(T));
  }
private:
  virtual bool SetData(const void* data, const std::type_info& tid) = 0;
}

template< class T >
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  bool DoSetData(const std::vector<T>& data)
  {
    // tbd
  }
private:
  virtual bool SetData(const void* data, const std::typeinfo& tid)
  {
    if( tid != typeid(T) )
      return false;
    const std::vector<T>* pdata = reinterpret_cast<const std::vector<T>*>(data);
    return DoSetData(*pdata);
  }
}
```

What say you?

Comment: lol seems very complicated to me, I don't have your skills; 
i think I should forget the virtual methods, I can't even remember why I put them (tied to boost.serialization, maybe).

By the way, I'm totally ready to choose boost.any, but the same question remains : does it allow me to access dats of my template class behind?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to implement type-erasure and then asking how you can make clients operate on the types that you're erasing.  The pattern that you're deploying here is only appropriate if the derived classes of `Base` have operations in common that can be called without reference to the concrete type of data that they store.  If there are no such common operations and the only semantically useful things for clients to do through your `Base` interface involve using the concrete types of the derived classes, then you won't be able to use this design.

Comment: ok my initial problem before I chose this solution was that in my main I'got vector<My_class<T> >; if type-erasure is not the soltuion, wat can I do ?

Comment: @user408535 I don't really understand your initial problem as described.  If clients of the interface need to know the underlying data type, then you either have to get rid of the interface or make it a template interface.  If you can formulate a set of functions for the interface that don't require the underlying data type, then you could leave it as a non-template interface.

Comment: problem is vector<My_class<T> > is in declaration so I don't possess T at this time and I get a compilation error

Comment: @user208535 right, that's why you would have to templatize `Base` if you want to keep that in your declaration, there's really no other way around it.  `Base` would have to have a template parameter `T` which would be the same `T` in your `My_class<T>`.

Comment: I mean that at first I had vector<Base<T> > in my int main() and with no way to provide T, so error; it became  vector<Base> witha derived template class

that's the purpose of type-erasure

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the user of the class must know what T is in order to work with datas in your derived type, even if they are accessing it through the base type.

You may be able to set up a somewhat generic interface with a void*, but the user of your class will still have to match up a each class instance to the specific type, T.  If T is int, users will have to know that collection is based on int.

If you want to store any type in the vector, without worrying about which instance is which type, you could make T void*.  If you do this, you could even skip the `template<typename T>` part of derived.  It could become a non-template class.

Comment: but if I keep T, there must be a template<typenename T> somwhere in Derived ?

Comment: @user408535: Yeah, I'm just saying if you decide to use void*, so that you can put any object together in the vector, you wouldn't necessarily need T anymore.

Comment: oh, ok but isn't void* dangerous ?

Comment: @user408535: In some senses, absolutely.  There is no type `safety`.  This means your program is free to behave badly at runtime rather than fail to compile.  If you are erasing the type, that is essentially what you hope to achieve anyhow.  Void* is safe if the consumer and producer treat it correctly, just like any other pointer.